Compile a one file ocaml program with a module and a main method
I somehow can't install a working OCaml environment on my Windows computer. I want to use know the OCaml online compiler. Problem: I can only write one file there and put everything in that one file:
module Atom = struct

  let hello name = print_string ( "Hello " ^ name );;

end

print_string "Hello, World!";
Atom.hello "Florian";

The above code produces the error:
Output:

File "./HelloWorld.ml", line 7, characters 0-12:
7 | print_string "Hello, World!";
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: Syntax error

Without the module Atom stuff, the print_string works! Is it not possible to define a module at the top of the file. Or where is the syntax error?

You are missing a ;; at the end of the module declaration:
module Atom = struct
  let hello name = print_string ( "Hello " ^ name )
end;;

print_string "Hello, World!";
Atom.hello "Florian"

Related documentation.

(Also remove trailing ;. Semicolones are (essentially) for separating expressions in OCaml, not for terminating them.)

Your module is a top-level definition, while the rest is an expression. Only the former should be at the top level of an OCaml program. Top-level definitions do not need to be separated by ;;, but top-level definitions and expressions do.
You could add a ;; to the end of your module definition to fix the error you're seeing, but you'd be better off making that expression part of a top level binding against (). A well-formed OCaml program should not contain ;;.
Of course, playing with code in a REPL is another matter.
module Atom = struct
  let hello name = 
    print_string ("Hello " ^ name)
end

let () =
  print_string "Hello, World!";
  Atom.hello "Florian"

You may also wish to use print_endline for more pleasing output, and to address potential output buffering issues.
module Atom = struct
  let hello name = 
    print_endline ("Hello " ^ name)
end

let () =
  print_endline "Hello, World!";
  Atom.hello "Florian"

As a further suggestion, you can use the Printf or Format module rather than string concatenation. The benefit in this case is minimal to nil, but for more complex prints, it can help to clarify your code.
module Atom = struct
  let hello name = 
    Format.printf "Hello %s\n" name
end

This also allows partial application:
module Atom = struct
  let hello = Format.printf "Hello %s\n"
end

A more complex example:
print_endline ("The product of " ^ string_of_int x ^ " and " ^ string_of_int y ^ " is " ^ string_of_int (x * y))

Or:
let sx = string_of_int x in
let sy = string_of_int y in
let sp = string_of_int (x * y) in
print_endline ("The product of " ^ sx ^ " and " ^ sx ^ " is " ^ sp)

Vs.
Format.printf "The product of %d and %d is %d\n" x y (x * y)

